# For bigger font in Swift UIPickerView row, should I replace titleForRow with viewForRow, or add viewForRow in addition to titleForRow?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

My two column (ie. 2 component) picker works great.
But some rows are truncated because picker doesn't have enough room for some rows.

All the online guides recommend:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!)
```

But, I'm confused:   do I replace titleForRow with viewForRow, or add viewForRow in addition to titleForRow?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple system-styled title, use titleForRow. If you want to use a custom view, use viewForRow. You cannot use both at the same time.

Comment: Tamas:  So, for a smaller font, I use viewForRow insteadof titleForRow, yes?

Comment: @DougNull Yes, that's correct.